# EXC_BAD_ACCESS error when changing views with PresentModalViewController

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, exc-bad-access

I'm trying to switch views in my app using this chunk of code:

```
self->variable1 = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:0];
self->variable2 = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:1];
self->variable3 = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:1];

[self presentModalViewController:titleScreen animated:YES];
```

If I comment out all of the allocated variable lines, the code works fine.  If it leave just 1 line in the code crashes with the "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" error.  Why is this happening?  The variables aren't being used at all, just declared for later use.  I'm not getting any compile errors on the lines either.  What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**
Thank you everyone for the help.  I change the way I declare my variables to @property/@synth to clean up my code, but it didn't fix the problem.  After a long time of fiddling I fixed it.  I changed the code from this:

```
self.variable1 = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:0];
```

to this:

```
self.variable1 = [NSNumber alloc];
[self.variable1 initWithInt:0];
```

and it worked!  Can someone explain why this worked and the first line didn't?

**Update:**

Thank you Peter Hosey for showing me my evil ways.  This time I'm pretty sure it's fixed.  I was storing my variable Releases in

```
-(void)release
```

I didn't realize xCode will release when it needs to.  I moved all the variable releases to

```
-(void)Destroy
```

so I can release everything on MY command.  Now the code works.  Thanks again!

Comment: Using the struct -> operator to reference an Objective-C property seems odd.

Comment: Are the variables declared as properties inside your class? Did you synthesize the accessor methods, or at least, implement them correctly? The use of `self` cause the setter method to be called, so the problem may be inside them.

Comment: `self.variable1 = <value>;` (assuming a `@property` and `@synthesize`) **would** invoke the setter. Using `self->variable1 = <value>;` **will not**. Though perfectly legal syntax (assuming `@public` ivars), not a good practice in Objective-C.

Comment: gschandler,
the reason I'm using self->... is this class owns other classes and both classes contain the same variable names.  One time I was working with a variable "language" and the app couldn't tell what class the language variable was coming from.  By adding self-> it eliminated confusion.  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @TerryWilcox: It's impossible. `->` references a variable, not a property.

Comment: "owns"? Do you mean "derived from"? Any ivar name collision should have been flagged at compile time. Otherwise, I would need to see an example to understand how you are having this issue that using `self->` would even begin to fix. I **can** see local variable declared within a method conflicting with ivar in the class, but then that's a matter of choosing a different local variable name to fix.

Comment: Related to what @gschandler noticed, classes cannot own other classes. Instances can own other instances. The distinction between classes and instances is an important one and misunderstanding it may be why you had a problem with a variable being unknown. Relevant documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/OOP_ObjC/ http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/

Comment: @JustinHeatherBarrios: You have not fixed the code; you have broken it. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: “xCode will release when it needs to”? Xcode is an IDE; it doesn't do anything in your program. Furthermore, that's only true under ARC, where the compiler will indeed insert code to release objects automatically. If you have `release` messages in your code, you must not be using ARC. See the Memory Management Programming Guide: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/ As for “`Destroy`”: Are you sure your releases wouldn't be better placed in `dealloc` rather than in some custom method of your own invention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you declare `variable1`, `variable2`, and `variable3` as properties, not instance variables. Then, use `self.variable1`, `self.variable2`, and `self.variable3` to access them.

The dot syntax (`self.variable1`, etc.) uses the memory management policy you declared on each property; the arrow syntax (`self->variable1`, etc.) will access the variables directly. The crash is because you created two arrays in away that doesn't leave you owning them, and then did not assign the arrays to a property that would retain them.

You may also want to upgrade your project to use ARC. Then there is no memory-management difference; assigning to the instance variables rather than the properties will not cause the object to be prematurely released, because ARC considers instance variables to be ownerships by default. You may still want to switch to using properties after you switch to ARC, but not to prevent a crash.

---

In response to your edit:

> I change the way I declare my variables to @property/@synth to clean up my code, but it didn't fix the problem.

Then something else was wrong.

You never did say much about the problem itself. You said you got an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`, but not what statement triggered the crash or on what grounds you blamed it on the code you showed.

> I changed the code from this:
>
> ```
> self.variable1 = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:0];
> ```

That's the correct code, though. That's what you should be using.

> to this:
>
> ```
> self.variable1 = [NSNumber alloc];
> [self.variable1 initWithInt:0];
> ```

Noooo! That code is wrong, wrong, wrong, on multiple levels.

`init` methods (including `initWithWhatever:` methods) are not guaranteed to return the same object you sent the message to. NSNumber's `initWithInt:` very probably *doesn't*.

That object creates an *uninitialized* NSNumber object and assigns that to the property. Then it sends `initWithInt:` to that object, which will return an initialized object, which *can be and **very probably will be a different object***. Now you are holding an uninitialized object (which you will try to use later) and have dropped the initialized object on the floor.

**Never, ever, ever send `alloc` and `init`(`With…`) in separate expressions. Always send them in the same expression. No exceptions.** Otherwise, you risk holding the uninitialized object rather than the initialized object. In your case (with NSNumbers), that is almost certainly what will happen.

What you should be doing is declaring and synthesizing a strong property that owns the NSNumber object, and creating the NSNumber object in a single statement: either `[[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:]` or `[NSNumber numberWithInt:]`. If you're not using ARC, you'll want the latter, since the property will retain the object. If you are using ARC, they're effectively equivalent.

And if you get a crash with that code, then *something else is wrong*, so please tell us—either in this question or in a new question—about the crash so we can help you find the true cause of it.

Answer (score 1):

`variable2` and `variable3` are being autoreleased before you actually access them (presumably) later after presenting the modal view.

At the very least change the lines to:

```
self->variable2 = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:1] retain];
self->variable3 = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:1] retain];
```

or

```
self->variable2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
self->variable3 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
```

`variable1` should be fine.

Best would be to use `@property` and `@synthesize` so you can use dot notation:

**.h**

```
@interface MyClass : SuperClass

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *variable2;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *variable3;

@end
```

**.m**

```
@implementation MyClass
@synthesize variable2,varible3;

- (void)foo {

    self.variable2 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:1];
    self.variable3 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:1];

}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, all instance variables in objective-c have protected scope. So unless you have explicitly declared them public in your interface file as:

```
@interface MYClass {

@public
    NSNumber *variable1;
    NSMutableArray *variable2;
    NSMutableArray *variable3;
}
//...
@end
```

then they will not be accessible using the struct dereferencing operator. This is likely the cause of those EXC_BAD_ACCESS errors.

Comment: The compiler would have thrown errors and prevented the build in the first place. So, this would not be the case.